# Specify arguments when registering apps in Window Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, run-dialog

I've gone through the [Application Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) article from Microsoft about running apps through the Run (Win + R) command.

Is it possible to include command line arguments when I'm registering apps this way? Like just specify a string to be included when executing the app.

I have tried including that string as part of the Default value when specifying the file path but that only results in Windows saying the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could pass arguments that way is, from what I understand from the article, in the (Default) entry, so, say, the application is "shutdown", so you will include in its (Default) path entry "%systemroot%/system32/shutdown.exe -r -t 0" (I have not tested this, you can try it with any application you know that supports whatever argument).

Windows will probably give you an error that it was unable to locate said application after you change its registry entry, so try to logoff or restart the computer after you change the key to make sure.

Comment: I have tried that and that was exactly the result. I forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: Have you tried to logoff/restart after making the change? If that doesn't works I really have no clue.